# Python combinations with replacement with random placement of values (list)

Tags: python, combinations

I am trying to create a list of combinations from a list ([0,1,2,4,6]).
I want combinations with 12 values.

```
Eg: 
"(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)"
"(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)"
"(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4)"
"(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)"
"(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4)"
"(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)"
"(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4)"
"(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6)"
"(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)"
```

This is working perfectly but now what I want to do is that the position of these values in each output should be random.
Something like:

```
"(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)" should be "(2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0)"
```

This is the code, I have written.

```
combinations_list = [comb for i in range(1, 13) for comb in combinations_with_replacement(numbers, i) if sum(comb) == match_points]
```

where match_points can be any number. Say, for the above output, match_points was 14. and numbers = [0, 1, 2, 4, 6]

How shall I randomise the combination values? Also, I need to restrict the count of 0s in the combination to 6.

Eg:

```
"(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 6, 6)"
"(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 6)"
"(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 6)"
```

shouldn't be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) your list.

```
import random

# .. code
random.shuffle(your_list)  # It does the shuffle inplace.
```

Comment: Thanks. this helped. :)